# How to get Ms test code coverage in sonar using jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to get code coverage in sonar using Jenkins. I have provided .run settings file for ms test code coverage  but it still not displaying the sonar dashboard.

I run these commands in my jenkins pipeline. /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=*.coverage"

How can i generate codecoveragexml file?could you please help me with that..

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the `dotnet test` command on the build server, with the proper parameters in order to generate coverage files. Add the following as a batch step in Jenkins.

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=[You project name].trx" --collect "Code Coverage" 
--results-directory:"[Your project path]\TestResults"
```

Note that `"Code Coverage"` text in the above command should match the `friendlyName` attribute of the `DataCollector` tag of your `run.settings` file.

When the above command is run, it creates a `.coverage` file which you need to convert into `.coveragexml`. But the generated file will have a random name so you need to rename it first.

```
ren *.coverage [Your project name].coverage
```

The following command does the conversion from `.coverage` to `.coveragexml`.

```
CodeCoverage analyze /output:[Your project name].coveragexml [Your project name].coverage
```

Finally, give the path of this `.coveragexml` file to Sonar:

```
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=[Your project name].coveragexml
```

PS: You may also give the `.trx` file to Sonar, which you created in the first step. Then sonar tells you more about the number of tests you have, the pass rate and stuff.

```
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=[Your project name].trx
```